# How to prove $Q = \{\,(a_n) ∈ l^{∞} : |a_n| ≤ 2^{−n}\text{ for all }n \in \Bbb N\,\}$ is a compact subset of $l^{∞}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness

Let $l^∞$ denote the vector space of all bounded sequences $x = (x_n)$ of real
numbers equipped with the norm
$\|x\| = \sup_{n∈\mathbb{N}} |x_n|$.
Show that the set
$Q = \{(a_n) ∈ l^{∞} : \hbox{$|a_n| ≤ 2^{−n}$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$}\}$
is a compact subset of $l^{∞}$.

I already prove $l^{∞}$ is complete and I think I should use sequential compactness to prove it.But I stuck.Any help is appricated.

[here is the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdUyl.jpg)
[here is the secodn page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHu7S.png)

Comment: First question - where do you get stuck when you try to use sequential compactness?

Comment: Sequential compactness is in fact a good way to begin with. A hint is that, since any convergent sequence in $l^{\infty}$ also converges pointwise, this should be also true for your convergent subsequence. There is a famous trick to extract such subsequence, which you are probably already aware of. Then you can ask yourself, "Is pointwise convergence enough or do I need more restrictions?" Answering to this question will indeed lead to a proof.

Comment: $\color{red}{\mathsf{And \ here \ is \ a \ spoiler}}$: A shorter proof is available once you know that pointwise convergence is enough for norm-convergence in $Q$. Consider the map $\varphi : [-1,1]^{\Bbb{N}} \to Q$ defined by $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}} \mapsto (2^{-n}x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous and $[-1,1]^{\Bbb{N}}$ is compact by the Tychonoff theorem, the image $Q = \varphi([-1,1]^{\Bbb{N}})$ is also compact.

Comment: I already upload my proof is that a legitimate proof?